# Fragments and Tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am creating an app in android studio and i am using the `TabbedActivity` within my app.

The `TabbedActivity` has a built in `FloatingActionButton` which is located in the main `TabbedActivity` and the tab pages are displayed using fragments

My question is how do I implement an `onClick` event for the `FloatingActionButton` to manipulate the `Fragments`

Comment: Handle 'onClick' event of FAB in Main Tabbed activity. You will get fragment state where you will come to know on which fragment you are currently. Based on the fragment position you handle click event of FAB and perform your action

Comment: You can find reference of fab button in fragment by fab = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);

Answer (score 0):

in your `Activity` create following method which will give current `Fragment`.

```
    public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=this.getFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    if(fragments != null){
        for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
            if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                return fragment;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

now in your `Floating Action Button` `onClick` method

```
onClick()
{
    Fragment current= getVisibleFragment();
      int id= current.getId();
    switch(id)
    {
        case R.id.frag1:
            //frag1 onclick
            break;
        case R.id.frag2:
            //frag2 onclick
            break;
        case R.id.frag3:
            //frag3 onclick
            break;
        case R.id.frag4:
            //frag4 onclick
            break;
        case R.id.frag5:
                //frag5 onclick
            break;
        default: //activity stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: it helps you or not?

Comment: Thank you very much but im still running into a problem.

Comment: In the getVisibleFragment method when instantiating the list, it doesnt recognise the “getFragments” part

Comment: it requires min api 26